# check all links Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

Im trying to automaticly test all the links on a site.
But the problem is that my foreach loop stops after the first click.

When I Console.log the attribute it writes out all the links but wont do the same when its time to Click around :)

This logs out all the links.

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
 public IWebElement hrefClick { get; set; }

    public void TestT2Links()
    {
        foreach (IWebElement item in PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
            
        }
    }
```

But when im trying to Click() function it only clicks the first link.

```
 [FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
 public IWebElement hrefClick { get; set; }

    public void TestT2Links()
    {
        foreach (IWebElement item in PropertiesCollection.driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")))
        {
            hrefClick.Click();
              
            Console.WriteLine(item.GetAttribute("href"));
        }
    }
```

I also tried the back method to back navigate after every click but also useless and wrong :(

```
PropertiesCollection.driver.Navigate().Back();
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to find **ALL** links. The `[FindsBy]` you are using returns **a** link not the list. First find a collection

```
[FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
public IList<IWebElement> LinkElements { get; set; }
```

**Edit**

Just heads up, simply clicking through a list of `WebElements` will possibly return `StaleElement` reference exception due to `DOM` refresh. Use `for loop` and find the element runtime.

```
[FindsBy(How = How.TagName, Using = "a")]
public static IList<IWebElement> LinkElements { get; set; }


private void LoopLink()
{
    int count = LinkElements.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[i].Click();
        //some ways to come back to the previous page
    }

}
```

Comment: I have tried that solution also but LinkElements wont use the Click() method.

Comment: Well, you cannot use foreach in that certain scenario any way. It will through `StaleElement` reference exception. But programmatically you should be able to

Comment: hmm. Will try to understand what you mean :) this is my second day with C# and Selenium so im really new at this.

Comment: See my edit. I kinds of tried to explain there. I ran into same situation and it's very common in `selenium`

Comment: I think I actually understand the problem here and the code took me to a secondpage. Need problably hassel a little bit more.
But THANK YOU for the explanation and help.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution without click

```
public void LoopLink() {
    int count = LinkElements.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        var link = LinkElements[i];
        var href = link.GetAttribute("href");

        //ignore the anchor links without href attribute
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(href))
            continue;

        using (var webclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = webclient.GetAsync(href).Result;
            Assert.That(response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(HttpStatusCode.OK));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
hrefClick.Click();
```

with

```
item.Click()
```

inside your foreach() loop

Comment: Well it still stops after the first link. :)